# Update UI Label when using Task.Factory.StartNew

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am trying to make my UI more responsive in my WPF app.  I spawn a new thread using

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => RecurseAndDeleteStart() );
```

In that method `RecurseAndDeleteStart()` I want to update a label in the UI with the file that is being deleted.

How does one accomplish this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since it's WPF, you can use the Dispatcher and call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to marshal the call back to the UI thread to update the label.

Alternatively, you can pass a TaskScheduler into your method, and use it to update the label as follows:

```
// This line needs to happen on the UI thread...
TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

Task.Factory.StartNew( () => RecurseAndDeleteStart(uiScheduler) );
```

Then, inside your method, when you want to update a label, you could do:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
  {
      theLabel.Text = "Foo";
  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
```

This will push the call back onto the UI thread's synchronization context.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: +1 for showing that a child task can be run on a different scheduler (and another +1 for showing me `CancellationToken.None` - I've been passing `new CancellationToken()` but it seemed a hack!)

Comment: +1 This solution is simple, and I didn't have to change to much in my project to implement it! Tried a few other solutions but couldn't implement them correcly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `label.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate)` to invoke anything from a different thread that will change the contents of the label.